# How to display the registered data from database in text field in Xamarin Forms to update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to `Update/Edit`the player details in my Xamarin Forms app. Once the player is logged in to the app, on click on the profile image should navigate to Player Details (`Register.xaml`) screen with `player details` populated from database. How to get the data displayed in text fields?

// The Register.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="20">           
            <Label Text="Player Details" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="25"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="fullNameEntry" Placeholder="Full Name" Text="{Binding FullName}"></Entry>
            <Entry x:Name="mobileEntry" Placeholder="Mobile" Text="{Binding Mobile}"></Entry>
            <Entry x:Name="soccerpostionEntry" Placeholder="Soccer Position" Text="{Binding SoccerPosition}"></Entry>            
            <Button Text="Register"  Clicked="RegisterSave_OnClicked" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="ForestGreen"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Below  `OnProfilePicClicked` will grab the logged in user from database

```
private async void OnProfilePicClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Navigate to Register screen with player data loaded:
            var emailText = emailEntry.Text;            
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Register(){});
            List<PlayerDetails> details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() where x.Email == emailText select x).ToList();
            if (details!= null)
            {
                // found the record
                PlayerDetails playerDetails = new PlayerDetails();
                playerDetails.FullName = details[0].FullName;
                playerDetails.Mobile = details[0].Mobile;
                playerDetails.SoccerPosition = details[0].SoccerPosition;
            }

        }
```

PlayerDetails model class:

```
string fullname;
        string mobile;
        string soccerposition;

        public PlayerDetails()
        {

        }

        public string FullName
        {
            set
            {
                if (fullname != value)
                {
                    fullname = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FullName"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return fullname;
            }
        }

        public string Mobile
        {
            set
            {
                if (mobile != value)
                {
                    mobile = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Mobile"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return mobile;
            }

        }

        public string SoccerPosition
        {
            set
            {
                if (soccerposition != value)
                {
                    soccerposition = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SoccerPosition"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return soccerposition;
            }
        }
```

Comment: typically you would load your data into a model and bind that to the controls on your page.  There are numerous articles and sample apps of how to do this.  What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: Pass the specific player's data to new page and show it.

Comment: I am struggling how to get particular player data from database and pass back to model view. Sorry,  I am very new to Xamarin Forms.. Can I get data via player email?

Comment: I will keep on trying anyway, thanks

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Do you now know how to write the SQL query, do you not know how to process the data? Please show in your question what you tried, and what exactly your problem is

Comment: "can I get player data via e-mail?" - do you mean can you lookup a player in your db via their e-mail address?  Probably - but you haven't shown us ANY relevant code for your data model or your database.

Comment: @Jason I have added my code, I am getting the logged in player details from database .I need to pass the data back to model / view ie Register.xaml. I have already done the Binding of fields,  but still not displaying the data. I know there should be something else !

Comment: First, you're pushing the new page BEFORE you do your db query.  Second, you're not actually passing any data to the new page.  @JackHua-MSFT answer below addresses both of these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You should `pass the model` when you pushing to Register page.

In your Register page, add a `PlayerDetails` parameter in the construction function and set `BindingContext` to the model：

```
public partial class Register : ContentPage
{
    PlayerDetails myDetails;

    public Register(PlayerDetails playD)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        myDetails = playD;
        BindingContext = myDetails;
    }
}
```

And when you push, pass the model:

```
private async void OnProfilePicClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Navigate to Register screen with player data loaded:
    var emailText = emailEntry.Text;
    List<PlayerDetails> details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() where x.Email == emailText select x).ToList();
    if (details != null)
    {
        // found the record
        PlayerDetails playerDetails = new PlayerDetails();
        playerDetails.FullName = details[0].FullName;
        playerDetails.Mobile = details[0].Mobile;
        playerDetails.SoccerPosition = details[0].SoccerPosition;


        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Register(playerDetails) { });
    }
    else {

        Console.WriteLine("Can't find the playerDetails");
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is working now, can we also change the label on the `Register` button to `Update` once we navigated to PlayerDetails ?

Comment: @soccerway Sure, binding the text of button like what you do on label.

Comment: Hua... Could you help me on how to fix this. All I would need to display data SoccerDailyStatus.xaml..but now the screen is flickering with exception...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978839/xamarin-forms-app-throws-sqlite-sqliteexception-could-not-open-database-file?noredirect=1#comment98645389_55978839

Comment: Hua, I have solved that in a different way, appreciate a lot for double checking with me